# parsing variable which contains vertical bar

Tags: tr, yad

I have a bash script that involves the output of `yad`. By default, `yad` outputs its results separated by pipe characters "`|`".

I have a string variable `output`.
Echoing it shows it contains this:

```
/dev/sde|
name0|name1|name2|
```

I want all those vertical bars changed to line breaks.

This does not work: `echo "$output" | tr '|' '\n'`
And neither does this: `echo "$output" > /tmp/output; echo $(cut -d'|' -f1 < /tmp/output)`
Both attempts result in only a line break being outputted. `/tmp/output` was created, and it contained two empty lines but not any text.

Comment: What shell are you using? Your `tr` command is working for me.

Comment: If `echo "$output" > /tmp/output` produces a file that contains two empty lines, then there is something else going on with your variable; please [edit] your question to include the output of  `printf '%s' "$output" | xxd` or similar

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us your operating system. Your `tr` command should work, so if it doesn't, it might be specific to whatever `tr` your operating system uses. ii) Explain what actually happens when you run the `tr`. Just telling is it doesn't work isn't very helpful. How does it fail? Are there any errors? Does it just not do anything at all? iii) Clarify if your `$output` variable contains multiple lines, with newlines, or just one.

Answer (score 1):

Your tr should be fine.

Try to escape `"\|"`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was going on: the variable was being set incorrectly.
Shortened:

```
yad --plug=12345 --tabnum=1 &
yad --plug=12345 --tabnum=2 &
output="$(yad --notebook --key=12345)"
echo "$output"
```

`$output` appeared to have been echoed since the results were printed to the terminal.
But removing the echo had no effect. Then I realized that *the first two commands were the ones outputting the data*, not the third & outer `yad` command.
Moving `output="$(` to the start of the first yad command solved the problem of the empty variable.

And, I browsed through `man yad` and discovered that there is a cli flag for just what I wanted:

```
--separator='\n'
```